# Magento Dataflow error: Method "parse" not defined in adapter

Tags: parsing, magento, methods, import

I have a method to import products, what I do is this, I create a new file in local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter and I override saveRow functions, this files  class is a extension of Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product.

And Everythings works fine IN LOCAL. No problems in my pc, in my local server. So it’s time to test it in the client server, I upload de file, the csv as well and when I execute at dataflow Advances profiles, I have this error:

**Method “parse” not defined in adapter catalog/convert_adapter_productconfigurable**

I repeat, I check it on local and it works, but not at the server.

I disable, flush then enable again cache, reindex data and I do not what more do. For a reason in the server do not find the class or something like that.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

There Must be some error in defining class name of the "local" code file please check classname of local file's product.php.

Answer (score 0):

1) instead of uploading the file i think you should explicitly write your new adapter class on the client server magento...and before that please check out the version conflicts 
2) if still the problem persists try calling the parent class parse method explicitly or override it...
hope this helps it....actly without knowing the code its hard to predict what you should do...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get to the bottom of problem is to check logs which are located in your magento root folder:

```
var/log/system.log
var/log/exception.log
```

My guess is that you haven't compiled the plugin. Please run in your admin panel System -> Tools -> Compile